# "both of them equals" or "both equal"?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, grammatical-number

I have **two things** that are the same, I'm just trying to say that in one of the following options but I'm confused because I don't know what is the correct.

> 1) Both equa**l**.
>
> 2) both equal**s**.
>
> 3) both **of them** equa**l**.
>
> 4) both **of them** equal**s**.
>
> 5) both **of them is** equal.
>
> 6) both **of them are** equal.
>
> 7) both **is** equal.
>
> 8) both **are** equal.

Comment: to each other or to something else? ​

Comment: It would be helpful if you focused on **one particular problem** in a given question, explaining what you think about it and why you're confused.  In this question, you're asking about three different things, so you've listed 2³=8 possibilities, but you haven't really asked anything specific about any of them.  Your three questions appear to be: ① Does *both* take singular or plural agreement? ② What is the difference between *both* and *both of them*? ③ Should you use the verb *equal* or the verb *be* with the adjective *equal* as a complement?

Comment: Variously exact dupes, possible dupes, and related questions in one or both ways can be found in: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/27327 http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/6373 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/159553 http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/31075  http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/24385 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/24846 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/22357 http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/54459 http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/62699 http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/30426 http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/16238 http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/24385 http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/62971

Comment: Several of the options could be correct depending on how they are used.  It would be helpful to provide the entire sentence you trying to write.

Comment: I edited it again

Comment: What's wrong with "They're both the same."?  Native speakers wouldn't use *equal* here at all.

Comment: So, when using in "equal"?

Comment: If the writer does not wish to expand the sentence to indicate whether said equality/equivalence/sameness is to/as *each other* or *something else*, then I think that it is best practice to avoid the word 'both', instead simply writing `they are equal/equivalent/same`.

Answer (score 1):

You use both for referring to two persons or things. So it takes a plural verb as follows:

Both equal, both of them equal, both of them are equal, and both are equal.